# How to define a GraphQL type model that contains complex objects?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql, graphcool

I am using the Facebook Graph API's data to get the user info and create my user in the GraphQL service (graphcool).

```
function createGraphcoolUser(facebookUser) {
    return api.request(`
      mutation {
        createUser(
          facebookUserId: "${facebookUser.id}"
          facebookEmail: "${facebookUser.email}"
          facebookName: "${facebookUser.name}"
          facebookPicture: "${facebookUser.picture}"
        ) {
          id
        }
      }`)
      .then((userMutationResult) => {
        return userMutationResult.createUser.id
      })
}
```

But `${facebookUser.picture}` is an object with nested fields.

```
{
  "id": "123467890",
  "email": "my@email.ca",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "url": "https://url.to.picture.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

So how do I define it in the type model ?

```
type User @model {
  # Required system field:
  id: ID! @isUnique # read-only (managed by Graphcool)

  # Optional system fields (remove if not needed):
  createdAt: DateTime! # read-only (managed by Graphcool)
  updatedAt: DateTime! # read-only (managed by Graphcool)

  facebookUserId: String @isUnique
  facebookEmail: String
  facebookName: String
  facebookPicture: ---> HERE <---

  posts: [Post!]! @relation(name: "UserPosts")
}
```

Comment: Can you just store the picture URL as a string? `facebookPicture: "${facebookUser.picture.data.url}"`

Comment: Yes i temporarily did that ... But i'd like to know how to store complexe objects.

Comment: You can make `facebookPicture` field a JSON type as well to keep the structure, but then you lose some validation abilities.

Comment: Ok will check this tomorrow, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question the info was in the docs (sorry about that):

We must use Input types

> ... you can also easily pass complex objects. This is particularly
>   valuable in the case of mutations, where you might want to pass in a
>   whole object to be created. In the GraphQL schema language, input
>   types look exactly the same as regular object types, but with the
>   keyword input instead of type ...

http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `facebookPicture` to be a type, I think there's a couple ways to do it.  It appears that the `data` object is just a wrapper, so it could help us to flatten the whole thing down.

```graphql
type User @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique

  facebookUserId: String! @isUnique # unique field should be required
  facebookEmail: String
  facebookName: String

  facebookPicture: FacebookPicture @relation(name: "UserPicture")

  posts: [Post!]! @relation(name: "UserPosts")
}

type FacebookPicture @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  user: User! @relation(name: "UserPicture")
  url: String!
}
```

Prior to Graphcool 1.0, it will force the relationship into being two-way, so you will have to handle having a `user` field in the image as well.  This might become a bit simpler after 1.0 is finally rolled out.

In order to add the image to the user, you can (should be able to) use a [nested mutation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/graphql-api/mutation-api-ol0yuoz6go/#nested-mutations). Something like:

```graphql
mutation createUserAndFacebookPicture { # this mutation should be generated by Graphcool
  createUser(
    # user stuff...
    facebookPicture: {
      url: "${facebookUser.picture.data.url}"
    }
  ) {
    id
    facebookPicture {
      id
      url
    }
  }
}
```

If there the `facebookUser.picture.data` is more complicated and not just a wrapper, then you could make a `data` field, and make that a `JSON` type.